# How retrieve data from an Excel file

Tags: javascript, sql, excel, jquery

How can we get a specific value from an Excel file if we don't have a header row in the file?
In my Excel file the first two lines are empty. I need the value at `Row 10`, `Column F`.

Comment: You are doing this from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you really are doing this in Javascript then maybe this will be what you need.

```
var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var book=excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\my.xls");
var sheet=book.Sheets.Item(1);
var value=sheet.Range("F10");
```

It's ActiveX though so this will only work in Internet Explorer. I got this code from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sidebargadfetdevelopment/thread/783724f0-526d-4c1d-a565-ebcdbca83cb8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an Excel-file from the server, you should use a suitable Excel-library. For example, use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) in ASP.NET.